# Trouble Linking object files from project in Tests

Tags: c++, linker, object-files, codelite

I am trying to link some of the object files so that I can write tests using UnitTest++ in the Codelite IDE. Mysteriously, the [tutorial](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/UnitTestPP) does not say how to use `.o` files from a (different) project.

If I was using the command line, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203592/how-can-i-link-an-o-file-using-g/2203609#2203609) shows me how to do that. However, I am having more difficulty in the Codelite editor. The accepted answer in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276901/linker-errors-when-trying-to-link-code-in-tests-using-unittest) says "[i]n the codelite's IDE, this is added in the linker's option textbox," however, I am not finding that to be the case.

I add the path to these `.o` files in the `Library Search Path` spot, and then I add the name of the individual files in the `Libraries` spot just below this. When I do this I get the `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<stuff>` error. If I omit the names of the specific files in the `Library` spot, I get the `undefined reference to` error.

Do I have to compile the original project as a library to get around this? Or is there a solution I don't see? The `my_class_test.cpp` file that I want to run looks something like this:

```
#include <UnitTest++/UnitTest++.h>

#include "my_class.h"

SUITE(MyClassTest)
{

class MCFixture
{
public:
    MyClass me;
    MCFixture() : me("a", "b", "c") {};
};

TEST_FIXTURE(MCFixture, ConstructorTest)
{
    CHECK_EQUAL(1.0, 1.0);
}

} //SUITE(MyClassTest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeLite assumes that the names you write in **Libraries** box are values you
want to pass to the linker `-l` option.

The linker option `-lfoo` directs the linker to search, first in the directories
you specify with the `-Ldir` option, then in its default search directories,
for either of the files `libfoo.so` (a shared library) or `libfoo.a` (a static
library). It stops searching when it finds either one. If it finds both or them in the same search directory it will prefer
`libfoo.so`. The selected library, if found, will be input to the linkage. Otherwise
the linker will given an error: `cannot find -lfoo`.

So, if you've specified a linker search directory - `/home/me/other/project/Debug`, say -
and in the **Libraries** box you've entered maybe `foo.o`, `bar.o`, then the
linker is going to search for files:

```
/home/me/other/project/Debug/libfoo.o.{so|a}
/home/me/other/project/Debug/libbar.o.{so|a}
```

which don't exist, and is going to tell you: `cannot find -l{foo|bar}.o`

There is a variation of the `-l` option, `-l:name`, which instructs the
linker that `name` is the *exact name* of the file to search for. So, if
you remove `foo.o`, `bar.o` from the **Libraries** box, and enter:

```
-l:foo.o
-l:bar.o
```

in the **Linker options** box, your linkage will succeed (barring other errors).

Of course, `foo.o` and `bar.o` are object files, not *libraries*, either static
or dynamic, so coercing the linkage to find them in library search is a bit of
a kludge even when you do it right.

It seems that you've written some application project and now you want to write
another project to unit-test functions and/or classes employed by the application.

This is a commonplace situation to which the standard solution is *three* projects:

- Project A: Builds a (static or shared) library that implements the components to be tested and exports their
  APIs.
- Project B: Builds your application, `#include`-ing the header file(s) and linking the library from Project A.
- Project C: Builds the unit-test runner, also `#include`-ing the header file(s) and linking the library from Project A.

Make Projects B and C depend on project A. In CodeLite you can do this with the **Build Order** project settings.

You'll find this solution more maintainable in the long run than keeping
the unit-test runner's linkage options up-to-date with whatever object files are generated by your application.